# Is it possible to have a table in database which is not mention in <myapp>DbContext file in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables `Shops`,`Locations`,`ShopLocations`. The `ShopLocations` table has only two columns shopId and locationId.

In the DbContext class I only have entry of Shop and Location.

1. So how did the `ShopLocations` table got created?
2. What needs to be done to access the `ShopLocations` using `_<myapp>DbContext.ShopLocations`?

```
public class <myapp>DbContext: XYZ {
   public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of reading about how many-to-many works in EF. E.g., look here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx (many-to-many section)  and here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: on 1.: ShopLocations in the FK Table for both tables Shops and Locations (Made up from Shop - first type + Location - second type + 's'). This is to flatten the many-to-many relationship to many-to-one + one-to-many. on 2.: ShopLocations has only the Key parts of both tables, so realistically you don't need to access it. however, shop.Locations.Select(x=>x.Id) (or in that sort) should do exactly that.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro using expression similar to Shop.Locations.Select(x=>x.Id) worked. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

'tis not entirely clear what you ask, but anyway.

1. It's the default behaviour of EF when it sees the many-to-many relationship. For instance, if your entity Shop has the collection of Locations and Location has the collection of Shops, on the db level EF will create an additional table.
2. You may create a class ShopLocation and map each Shop to many ShopLocations and each Location to many ShopLocations. ShopLocation in its turn will have two properties: for Shop and Location. Then, you would add the DbSet of ShopLocations to the context just like with the Shop and Location. However, I wouldn't recommend doing so since if your entity ShopLocations doesn't have any additional data to it, I don't think it should be present in your class structure. It depends, of course.

An example of class structure:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShopLocation> ShopLocations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShopLocation> ShopLocations { get; set; }
}

public class ShopLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I expect someone put it in there, maybe the dba, maybe someone else. Look at the definitions for shop and location in your code and do the same for shoplocations.

Comment: "Someone" is Entity Framework. This is how many-to-many association behaves by default.